# using tag within align

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align}
[m] &= [n] \nonumber \\

  &= b  
\refstepcounter{equation}
\label{eq:m}
\tag{\theequation,~tag}
\end{align}
```

If I cross reference the equation, with `Equation~\ref{eq:m}`, I want only the equation number, without the word 'tag'. Can this be done? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Use `\ltx@label`, which is the default `\label` inside a display environment. From the [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.pdf):

> ... we store the default definition of `\label` in `\ltx@label` and then define a
>   new version of `\label` for use in math display environments. `\label@in@display`
>   merely issues a warning message if there is already a pending label (which will
>   be discarded) and then stores the label in `\df@label`.

Below I've wrapped it inside a user interface `\ltxlabel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  [m] &= [n] \nonumber \\
      &= b \refstepcounter{equation}\ltxlabel{eq:m}\tag{\theequation,~tag}
\end{align}
See Equation~\ref{eq:m}.
\end{document}
```

Since you're using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), you may consider using `\eqref`.